# Understanding the returned value of `decode-time` (elisp)

Tags: elisp

After reading the documentation of `encode-time` and `decode-time` I'm not understanding how they work.

My trouble from comes from the fact that `encode-time` returns *two* values, whereas I'm expecting only one (the number of seconds since the UNIX epoch). What do these two values mean exactly?

```
ELISP> (encode-time 0 0 0 1 1 1970 t)
(0 0)
ELISP> (encode-time 0 0 0 1 1 1971 t)
(481 13184)
```

I get even more confused because these three calls work, but I don't understand how to interpret the argument in the first two cases:

```
;; Ok this is what I expect from the documentation
ELISP> (decode-time
        (encode-time 0 0 0 1 1 1971 t))
(0 0 0 1 1 1971 5 nil 0)

;; This is also what I expected, given it's the same than above, but I don't understand the meaning of the arguments
ELISP> (decode-time '(481 13184))
(0 0 0 1 1 1971 5 nil 0)

;; I kind of understand the following: here 481  is considered the seconds since UNIX epoch,
;; and 13184 is the difference in seconds from UTC.
;; The returned value, is the date (UNIX epoch + 481 seconds)
;; expressed in a timezone 13184 seconds ahead of UTC (45 47 3 1 1 1970 = 13665 seconds
;; and 13665−13184 = 481) 
ELISP> (decode-time 481 13184)
(45 47 3 1 1 1970 4 nil 13184)
```

Note that for all the examples above I have set `(set-time-zone-rule t)` to avoid having to deal with timezones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the documentation:

> `(decode-time &optional TIME ZONE)`
>
> Decode a time value as (SEC MINUTE HOUR DAY MONTH YEAR DOW DST UTCOFF).
>   **The optional TIME should be a list of (HIGH LOW . IGNORED),
>   as from ‘current-time’** and ‘file-attributes’, or nil to use the
>   current time.  It can also be a single integer number of seconds since
>   the epoch.  The obsolete form (HIGH . LOW) is also still accepted.

So we can see that the expected format is a list with the values "HIGH" and "LOW" (and maybe some extra information).  Following that direction to `current-time` gives us further explanation:

> `(current-time)`
>
> Return the current time, as the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00.
>   The time is returned as a list of integers (HIGH LOW USEC PSEC).
>   HIGH has the most significant bits of the seconds, while LOW has the
>   least significant 16 bits.  USEC and PSEC are the microsecond and
>   picosecond counts.

Why does Emacs use this seemingly-complicated format?  Undoubtedly the answer is simply that Emacs is old, and it needed to work with systems where only 16-bit integers were available.

Looking to the manual, <kbd>M-x</kbd> `elisp-index-search` for `current-time` takes us to `(elisp)Time of Day`:

> Most of these functions represent time as a list of four integers
>   ‘(SEC-HIGH SEC-LOW MICROSEC PICOSEC)’.  This represents the number of
>   seconds from the “epoch” (January 1, 1970 at 00:00 UTC), using the
>   formula: HIGH * 2**16 + LOW + MICRO * 10**−6 + PICO * 10**−12.  The
>   return value of ‘current-time’ represents time using this form, as do
>   the timestamps in the return values of other functions such as
>   ‘file-attributes’ (*note Definition of file-attributes::).  In some
>   cases, functions may return two- or three-element lists, with omitted
>   MICROSEC and PICOSEC components defaulting to zero.
>
> **Function arguments, e.g., the TIME argument to ‘current-time-string’,
>   accept a more-general “time value” format, which can be a list of
>   integers as above, or a single number for seconds since the epoch, or
>   ‘nil’ for the current time.  You can convert a time value into a
>   human-readable string using ‘current-time-string’ and
>   ‘format-time-string’, into a list of integers using ‘seconds-to-time’,
>   and into other forms using ‘decode-time’ and ‘float-time’.**  These
>   functions are described in the following sections.

Hence you can, for example, pass a single 32-bit Unix timestamp integer to `decode-time`

```
(decode-time 1554670400)
=> (20 53 8 8 4 2019 1 nil 43200)
```

You can also use `format-time-string` to obtain a single integer value:

```el
(string-to-number (format-time-string "%s" (current-time)))
```

Answer (score 2):

`(481 131184)` represents the number of seconds as `(HIGH LOW)` where `HIGH` is the upper bits and `LOW` is the lower 16 bits.  I.e. the real number of seconds is

```
(+ (* 481 65536) 13184) == 31536000
```